# Jersey @Component / Configuration class

Tags: jersey-2.0

could someone help me to write correctly Jersey Configuration class? So I'm using xml file as guide line for my upload and download webapp. I don't know how to register download service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<display-name>Jersey-UP-DOWN-Image-File</display-name>

<!-- Jersey Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <!-- Register resources and providers -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.jersey.series.upload.download.service</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- welcome file -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

For now my config class looks like:

```
import Images_WebApp.Images_WebApp.Resource.ImageResource;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(ImageResource.class);
        register(MultiPartFeature.class);

    }
}
```